# How to make sure Angularjs dependencies are working with 3rd party modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

We have this project at work where we use Angularjs. Together with AngularJS we are using Leaflet directive, Bootstrap etc.

The problem now is that the project is getting relatively large and we are actually selling the product. I have been given the responsibility to manage versions and find out a good way of making sure when we upgrade(for example) AngularJS, that all other components will work. Same with the other modules, if we upgrade bootstrap, how can i make sure that the AngularJS version that we are currently running is compatible?

I used to work with Perl before, and i know CPAN has great solutions for this, where it actually upgrades those dependencies that need to be upgraded.

Any help and tip would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is where http://bower.io/ helps, and writing good testing of course.

Comment: can you clarify what backend are you using? node.js, php, etc.

Comment: Sorry for not responding to this earlier, been on a long vacation. We ended up using yeoman to solve our problems. Thanks for the answers anyways.